# Mesos: Is it optional to use containers?

Tags: containers, mesos

Let me know if my understanding is correct:

- By default, a Mesos executor is a process in a slave node. It does not isolate from other process as clean as containers.
- Mesos supports containers that are mainly used for resource isolation. It is **optional**, not mandatory to use.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quote from [Mesos in Action](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/6/4e0f202-c1c7-4cd1-8cea-db8363300753/sample_ch01_Ignazio_Mesos_April27.pdf)

> **NOTE** In addition to Docker and cgroups, Mesos provides another means of isolation for other POSIX-compliant operating systems:
>   posix/cpu, posix/ mem, and posix/disk. It’s worth noting that these
>   isolation methods don’t isolate resources, but instead monitor
>   resource use.

By default POSIX isolators are enabled so they do not isolate proceses and as you see isolation is optional.